# x-editable ajax call does not process the designated url

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

Im using bootstrap with x-editable and im trying to get it working once the save button from x-editable is clicked the php file should be executed.

Ive tried everything within my knowledge to fix this but im not a hardcore javascript programmer so changing it to Json to give it a try is to my perspective a little much effort.

Ive read the documentation of x-editable and this should be the way to work with it.

So here is the html:

```
  <a href="#" class="username">superuser</a>
```

The Javascript:

```
      $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

      $('.username').editable({
           type: 'text',
           pk: 1,
           url: 'post.php',
         });
```

Once the **post.php** is missing x-editable gives an error , however if it sees the php file it does nothing.
the contents from the php file are irrelevant because there is only a  console log with test in it there.

The console log is never executed and i cant figure out why it is not working, I've seen 1 or 2 problems like thing one on Stackoverflow etc however no use full information.

This is the first time ever i had to ask something on the internet so i hope someone can help me with this one.

I've tried things like changing the `url` to `localhost/dir/etc` however no effect.
also setting `/posturl`, and adding var `posturl = "post.php";` didn't help

oh and I've tested all the resources : but if it helps here:

```
<!-- Le styles -->  
<!-- jQUERY -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Sharre -->
<script src="recources/assets/js/jquery.sharrre-1.3.4.js"></script>
<!-- Minnified bootstrap -->
<script src="recources/assets/min/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="recources/assets/css/pagestyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- X - Editable -->
<link href="recources/assets/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- External link -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.4/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 28):

Use `send` parameter as it can determine *Strategy* for sending data to server. It Can be **auto** | **always** | **never**. When 'auto' data will be sent on server only if `pk` and `url` defined, *otherwise new value will be stored locally*.

You can set it for all inputs by this code:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.send = "always";
```

Or Customize each input for related strategy like this:

```
$('.username').editable({
    send: 'always'
});
```

Comment: This is a better explanation and example.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried modifying the send option ?

```
$('.username').editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: 1,
    url: 'post.php',
    send: 'always'
});
```

Otherwise try debugging the unminified version bootstrap-editable.js and add a breakpoint here https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/blob/master/src/editable-form/editable-form.js#L189. I had a similar issue and that's what I did. Hope that helps.