# Why X-editable does not send AJAX request to send the modified data?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg, x-editable

I embedded the x-editable:

in the html:

```
<a class='doc_title editable' id='doc_title_12345' data-name="doc[title]" data-title="Enter doc title" data-type="text" data-url='/docs/12345' href='#doc_title_12345'>My Document<a>
```

in the js:

```
// turn to inline mode
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

// turn on editable on title
$('.doc_title.editable').editable();
```

I can edit in browser, but when I click on `save` nothing happens (I mean I see the new value, but it does not send via AJAX request to the server)

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 9):

As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802006/x-editable-ajax-call-does-not-process-the-designated-url?rq=1) mentioned it is required to add the `always` parameter:

```
$('.username').editable({
    send: 'always'
});
```

I didn't find it in the documentation (in the `Getting started`)

Comment: more specifically, the docs say this: Strategy for sending data on server. Can be auto|always|never. When 'auto' data will be sent on server only if pk and url defined, otherwise new value will be stored locally.